# Supabase self host: how to connect with nodejs and prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma, supabase

I have self hosted supabase on a VM on Digital ocean. I can access the dashboard through <ip-address>:3000

I have used nginx for proxy passing and also added SSL certification with a custom domain.

I am using a node app with prisma ORM. Prisma requires a DB URL string to get connected. Where can I find the URI string on self-hosted supabase? I have used the online supabase where the db uri, bucket link is given. I want to move my existing app to self hosted supabase. What is the procedure here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jwt password was generated for the DB while self hosting. That is the password for DB and default username is postgres.